Integral decomposition
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a separably acting von Neumann algebra and let $$\mathcal{A}\cong \int_{\Gamma}^{\oplus} \mathcal{A}_{\gamma}\,d\mu(\gamma)$$ be its direct integral decomposition into factors $\mathcal{A}_{\gamma}$ for $\mu$-a.a. $\gamma\in\Gamma.$
Can we claim that $$\mathcal{A}\mathbin{\bar\otimes} \mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))\cong \int_{\Gamma}^{\oplus} \mathcal{A}_{\gamma}\mathbin{\bar\otimes} \mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))\,d\mu(\gamma)?$$

Pretty sure this is true, though I don’t know if it’s explicitly written down anywhere. I’d suggest first proving the corresponding result for Hilbert spaces, then the $\subset$ inclusion is obvious. For the $\supset$ direction, follow the definition in Takesaki (Definition IV.8.17 and Theorem IV.8.18) and use separability to approximate an element of the direct integral by “simple functions” (in the sense that it is a finite concatenation of elements written as finite linear combinations of simple tensors). These approximating elements are clearly in the LHS, so you get the result.

Alternatively, perhaps after proving the Hilbert space analogue of this, use the characterization of commutants in Theorem IV.8.18 in Takesaki, first on the Hilbert space direct integral (without tensoring with $\ell^2$), then on the Hilbert space direct integral tensor $\ell^2$. This should be enough to get the result in your case, since you’re tensoring with $\mathcal{B}(\ell^2)$.

Thanks @DavidGao. So, if this really true then we can claim that every separably acting type $II_{\infty}$ vNa (not necessarilly a factor) is of the form $\mathcal{A} \bar \otimes \mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$ for a type $II_1$ vNa $\mathcal{A}.$

I don’t think it obviously follows from this. What I described is a proof that goes from left to right. In order to go the other way around, you’d have to more uniformly (or, maybe more precisely, in a measurable manner) choose the $\mathcal{B}(\ell^2)$ tensor component on each fiber. Regardless, what you said is true, and you don’t need any direct integral theory for that. This is Proposition V.1.40 in Takesaki, which even applies to the nonseparable case.
